# in libreoffice, find and search columns when one has something, the other is empty

Tags: libreoffice

one column has nothing, the cell is empty, the other column has a string

how do I find those?   there are columns A and B in my sheet, and I need to find the rows in column A that have something written on them, but in column B have nothing

both A and B should have something written on them. Most rows have that, all I need is a function that let´s me find those rows with only column A with value and column B with nothing

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should filter column B. It will be much easier and does not need a formula.

1. Select your range/columns, click on Auto Filter. Click OK if a message ask to set the first row as headers (choose it if the first row contains headers).
2. Click on the arrow next to the header of column B. Select empty, de-select the others. Click OK.

The rows will be filtered: only rows with values on Column A and empty values on Column B will be listed. See image below.

[image]

Comment: super! learnt a lot   tried with autofilter and works   Thank you so much!

Comment: Please visit the [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour) and [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers).